# Google.Apis.IdentityToolkit.v3 does not have SetProjectConfig method in .NET

Tags: .net, firebase, google-api

I wanted to enable email/password authentication for my firebase project using .NET library. And the library used to implement this case is Google.Apis.IdentityToolkit.v3, but I couldn't find the setProjectConfig method, what should I do?

In this link https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/identitytoolkit/v3/python/latest/identitytoolkit_v3.relyingparty.html it lists the method and setProjectConfig is available, but after installing it I couldn't find the method.

Answer (score 1):

The nugget package [Google.Apis.IdentityToolkit.v3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.IdentityToolkit.v3)  was last updated in 2014.

[image]

The link address for the project is https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/

Which means this is part of the .net library from before it was moved to github.
And may have been one of the old google data api's which are all dead now.

I am in contact with the team to see if we can get that package taken down.

I know thats probably not the answer you were looking for but i have checked.   I dont see that as part of the Google cloud .net client library either and its not part of the current google apis client library.   Mainly because firebase is not part of google apis, which are all pre generated libraries from the discovery services api.

Probably not the answer you were looking for but I am in contact with the team and will let you know if I hear anything more.

Comment: Yes that will be great DalmTo, let me know what the team will say to you, if there are other alternatives to implement the use-case I specified in the question.

Comment: I would start here [firebase-admin-dotnet](https://github.com/Firebase/firebase-admin-dotnet)   I will see if i can find some time to give it a try myself tomrrow.

Comment: I got a message back from the team they will look at it after the new year.  The issue is that they cant delist every obsolete package unless they could figure out how to automate it which is probably not possible.    So as i said dont use that package.

Comment: ohhh thank you DalmTo, is there other alternative library that I should use , the one above you mentioned firebase-admin-dotnet? what do you recommend?

Comment: @Samaritan I havent actually tried firebase with dot.net much I will see if i can find some time after the new year its worth a shot.   I plan on starting with that one and see what else i can dig up along the way.